# What is the simplest way to access a deep List of Lists in python?

Tags: python, list

I have a big list that its elements are also lists, and their elements also lists.
**for example:**

```
GrandFather= [Father1, Father2, Father3]

Father1= [Child1, Child2, Child3]
Father2= [Child4, Child5, Child6]
Father3= [Child7, Child8, Child9]

Child1 =[7,1]
Child2 =[6,2]
Child3 =[5,3]
Child4 =[4,4]
Child5 =[3,5]
Child6 =[2,6]
Child7 =[0,7]
Child8 =[1,8]
Child9 =[0,9]
```

So, if I have only the GrandFather List, and I want to access the leaves elements which are the elements inside each Child, I will have to write:

```
   for father_index in GrandFather:
       for child_index in GrandFather[father_index]:
           for leaf_index in GrandFather[father_index][child_index]:
               print( GrandFather[father_index][child_index][leaf_index ])
```

You can notice the complexity of accessing the leaves elements, actually the real list I have is much deeper than that.
So, my question here is **Is there a simpler way to access the leaves directly?**

Comment: Iterating over a list gives you the elements of the list, NOT indexes.  Your code would just be `for father in GrandFather:` / `for child in father:` / `for leaf in child:` / `print(leaf)`.

Comment: Your lists are defined backwards. Children need to come first to avoid an NameError

Comment: If you actually ran that loop, you would see that that's not how you access elements. `for` loop iterates over elements, not indices.

Answer (score 0):

There is no algorithm in the default Python libraries you can use `itertools.chain.from_iterable` comes close, but does not yield the individual values in the children.

Luckily the algorithm is easy to write:

```
def flatten(l):
    for value in l: 
        if isinstance(value, list): 
            yield from flatten(value)
        else: 
            yield value
```

You can now iterate over each element with

```
for a in flatten(GrandFather): 
  print(a)
```

Comment: This seems overkill given that the list has a fixed depth

Answer (score 0):

Python `for` loops iterate over elements, not indices. The *actual* loop would look like this:

```
for father in grandfather:
    for child in father:
        for leaf in child:
            print(leaf)
```

As you can see, the nested loops are a bit annoying, but the complicated indexing is a figment of your imagination.